# Restructuring Pandas DataFrame rows to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
itemname participant s0  s1  s2  s3
E1       1           no  no  no  yes
E1       2           no  no  yes no
E1       3           no  no  no  yes
A1       1           no  no  no  yes
A1       2           no  no  no  yes
A1       3           yes no  no  no
Foo      1           no  no  no  yes
Foo      2           yes no  no  no
Foo      3           no  yes yes yes
```

which I need to convert to the following format:

```
itemname  participant_1  participant_2  participant_3 
E1_s0     no             no             no 
E1_s1     no             no             no 
E1_s2     no             yes            no 
E1_s3     yes            no             yes 
A1_s0     no             no             yes 
A1_s1     no             no             no 
A1_s2     no             no             no 
A1_s3     yes            yes            no 
Foo_s0    no             yes            no      
Foo_s1    no             no             yes
Foo_s2    no             no             yes
Foo_s3    yes            no             yes
```

How can I combine each *itemname* with *s0, s1, s2* and *s3* as rows while differentiating among participants (where each participant should become a separate column)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
>>> df.pivot(
         columns='itemname',index='participant').T
         .swaplevel(axis='index')
         .sort_index(0).reset_index()
         .assign(itemname=lambda x:(x.pop('itemname')+'_' + x.pop('level_1'))
       ).set_index('itemname').add_prefix('participant_')

participant participant_1 participant_2 participant_3
itemname                                             
A1_s0                  no            no           yes
A1_s1                  no            no            no
A1_s2                  no            no            no
A1_s3                 yes           yes            no
E1_s0                  no            no            no
E1_s1                  no            no            no
E1_s2                  no           yes            no
E1_s3                 yes            no           yes
Foo_s0                 no           yes            no
Foo_s1                 no            no           yes
Foo_s2                 no            no           yes
Foo_s3                yes            no           yes
```

Comment: @user9397006 if the answer was useful, you may consider upvoting :)

Comment: Yes, sure :) Thank you, the answer was super helpful!